# Is it possible to access firebase console on IE Browser?

Tags: firebase, internet-explorer, firebase-console

I am trying to access to firebase console by VBA script, therefore i have to use IE as the browser.

My browser is stuck after i logged in to firebase with my gmail account, here is the screenshot after i logged in.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the loader animation is not playing. What IE version are you using? Can you try with the latest Edge browser? If that doesn't work, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The OP says they want to use VBScript, but Edge doesn't support VBScript.

Comment: Please post your VBScript that you're using - how are you interfacing VBScript with Firebase? (and **why** are you using VBscript?)

Comment: I am using IE 11, and I encountered this problem when I tried to login to the Firebase manually. Therefore i think this problem is not related to the VBScript

Comment: I think firebase console is not compatible with IE 11. I also get the same result as your screenshot when I try to access the website in IE 11.